# Kubernetes pods replica CPU usage is high

Tags: kubernetes, memory-management, microservices, cpu-usage

We have microservices running AWS EKS cluster and many of the microservices having more than 10 pod replicas, for monitoring we are using grafana. unfortunately some of the pods in same microsevices are showing very high CPU usage say 80% and some are lke 0.35%. we have understanding like kubernetes will do the load balancing equally to distribute load. What we are missing here.?

Answer (score 1):

How traffic is distributed from outside the cluster to your pods depends on the Load Balancer Controller, e.g. [AWS Load Balancer Controller](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.4/how-it-works/).

But the Load Balancer Controller typically does not take CPU usage in consideration, it only spreads traffic evenly to your replicas.

Typically, CPU load depends heavily on what your replicas are doing, e.g. some paths may use more CPU and some other HTTP paths is easier to handle. You need more insight to decide what to do, e.g. add some caching.